# Wordpress URL is replacing with load balancer URL

Tags: wordpress, nginx, haproxy

I am using one wordpress site. In this wordpress URL I am using 2 load balancing URL in my production.

For Example My actual URL is

```
www.myurl.com
```

My load blancer URL's are

```
www.myurl01.drd.myurl.com
www.myurl02.drd.myurl.com
```

For wordpress current URL I am using the following function in function.php

```
function current_url() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if( isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ) {
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

This function returning `www.myurl01.drd.myurl.com` load balancer URL instead of  `www.myurl.com`. how can get my actual URL using this function.

Any one please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `current_url()` does not handle the case where WordPress is running behind a proxy. Values in the `SERVER` array corresponding to the keys: `HTTPS`, `SERVER_PORT` and `SERVER_NAME` relate to the back-end server only.

The front-end proxy server may set specific headers to enable the back-end to detect that it is running behind a proxy. The WordPress core functions already support these extra settings and you may wish to look at those implementations before you make changes to your code.

If you want a quick fix (and assuming that your proxy server sets the value correctly) using `HTTP_HOST` in the place of `SERVER_NAME` may solve the immediate problem.

For a complete fix, you may want to look at using `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT`. If these values are defined, they should be use instead of the local equivalent.